# Macro within longtable handling

Tags: macros, longtable

I got two questions regarding the handling of longtable items:

---

### **1.**

I predefined some macros for a better handling of my longtables. In my style file I got this for a non-final row end:

```
\newcommand{\tableRowEnd}
{
    \\ \midrule
}
```

and this for my last row end:

```
\newcommand{\lastTableRowEnd}
{
    \\ \addlinespace
}
```

As a result I have to know which row is my last, to prevent a double line at the end of my table, however I want a addlinespace there. Is there a better way, so that I do not have to take care of the last row?

---

### **2.**

I am using a macro within my longtable to differ between two different builds, which are triggered via pdflatex from a script outside. Dependent on the build options, I do or do not want some rows in my table. Therefore I created this:

```
\newcommand{\tableEntryRelease}[2]
{
  \ifdefined\isReleaseBuild
    #1
  \else
    #2
  \fi
}
```

Using it that way:

```
[Longtable...]
\tableEntryRelease{\xxx}{
5 & Info & Description \tableRowEnd
6 & AnotherInfo & More Description \lastTableRowEnd
}
[... Longtable]
```

My question goes to #2: if I want to color all rows which are inserted here, how can I accomplish that? Using the \rowcolor command will only color the first row, not the following ones. I could use my macro seperatly for all "non-release" entries, however I prefer a solution with only one command.

---

Thanks in advance.

---

As two question were ask and no MWE was provided, I opened a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378236/coloring-longtable-rows-via-macro).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please ask only one question per question! And note that you can improve your chance to get a good answer by adding a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of only a code snippet. Without MWE every helper needs to make a speculative example to reproduce the problem and test her/his suggestions.

Comment: hard to answer fragments but I'll note that you are missing a lot of `%` at the ends of lines of this code which could affect the width of the table columns.

Comment: Ouch, ok I got that. I thought due to not having a compiling problem (my code works) but only a question about programming technique, this would be enough here. Anyway, I will provide a MWE tomorrow.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Good point mentioning the %s, I just missed them. However, this fragments work the way I posted them, trailing spaces are not a problem here.

Comment: they won't generate an error but they will (in general) add space tokens to the last column which can if you are unlucky affect the column width,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for pointing this out. I will take this into consideration when reworking my code.